# tesseract parameter to reduce noise in the image

Tags: tesseract

I am using tesseract for 2 months now and using opencv for reducing the dots/noise in the images. But I am trying to solve this issue at tesseract level. 
Is there any tesseract parameter to remove the background dots?
or can i tell the tesseract not to recognize the dots(depending on the size)?

I am very thankful if anyone guides me on this issue.

For the image below:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TjN6.png

I am getting the output like.

lb ane a a a ee ee
Ee ah Tani ANOTES tsi Ca Ee RR
RAT TE CORRE NE Re ele TTR a ee Tol a te es
see Â© Students should schedile 21 points of work sech years...
fen Es ee EE i ea
| fdvenced Coreral Sciemes Â©. |. eroral Home Feonomits (limited to.
Co mlgebras i ULE LE cl BE unions andi sentors) Dh
7od 1 Artâ€™ SpeelaliAvt [for those tC meman Ta GET
Lhd recommended by Art Supervisor. ii Industrial Arts hal

I am using below command to run tesseract:
tesseract --psm 6 --oem 1 image.png output_text_file

Comment: Did you try to blur the image? Maybe this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/getting-started-with-tesseract-part-ii-f7f9a0899b3f/) will be useful.

Comment: yes, if I blur the image before doing ocr, I can see some improvement but i want to eliminate the dots completely. That's the reason i am looking for tesseract parameter to get rid of this.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any noise removal option at the tesseract level as the preprocessing methods can't be generalized for all images.You can use denoising methods in opencv like  fastNlMeansDenoising, Dilation ,Erosion etc.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am trying to solve this issue at tesseract level....rather using additional tool like OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

tesseract is OCR engine and not image manipulation tool.